# Submit array with GTK callback function

Tags: c, arrays, callback, gtk

I have a lot of check buttons (cbuttons[]) in my main function.

After click of the install button, the array with the check buttons are commited.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

GtkWidget *cbuttons[13];

[...]

for(i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    cbuttons[i] = gtk_check_button_new_with_label(cbuttons_label[i]);
    gtk_toggle_button_set_active(GTK_TOGGLE_BUTTON(cbuttons[i]), TRUE);
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(vbox_lcbuttons), cbuttons[i], FALSE, TRUE, 0);
    gtk_widget_show(cbuttons[i]);
 }

   [...]

   g_signal_connect(button_install, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(install), &cbuttons);

}
```

Now I want to analyse the state of the different buttons with data[] but it doesn't work:

warning: dereferencing 'void *' pointer.

I'm new with GTK. Maybe it is the wrong way to do this? Can anybody help me to the right way?
(Sorry for my bad english. I'm not so familiar with the language.)

```
void install(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data) {

if(gtk_toggle_button_get_active(GTK_TOGGLE_BUTTON(*data[0]))) {
    func1();
}
  if(gtk_toggle_button_get_active(GTK_TOGGLE_BUTTON(*data[1]))) {
    func2();
  }
  [...]

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to convert the generic (`gpointer`, which is just a synonym for `void *`) pointer to a properly typed one, in your callback:

```
static void install(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data)
{
    GtkWidget **widgets = data;

    if(gtk_toggle_button_get_active(GTK_TOGGLE_BUTTON(widgets[0]))) {
      func1();
    }
    if(gtk_toggle_button_get_active(GTK_TOGGLE_BUTTON(widgets[1]))) {
      func2();
    }
   [...]
}
```